# SwiftUI TabView open last selected tab

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I've implemented TabView with 2 tabs and possibility to popToRootView. But now i wonder if it's possible to somehow open last visited View if i tap on unselected tab ?
What i mean:
I have tab1 and tab2

1. User tap on tab1 and see RootView of tab1, the goes to ViewA and goes next to ViewB.
2. Then he taps on tab2 and when he taps back to tab1 he sees RootView of tab 1

But how can send him to ViewB not RootView of tab 1

I go to Choose category -> Choose level -> Choose lesson and I change the tab to Profile. Then I change the tab to Home and I’m taken to the root but could i keep the user on the Choose lesson screen when they switch from another tab? In order words - can we make “pop to root view controller” work only when the currently selected tab is the Home one?

TabView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var tabState = TabState()

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $tabState.selectedTab) {
        NavigationView {
            if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "onboardingShown") as? Bool) == true {
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), isActive: $tabState.showTabRoots[0]) {
                    LogInScreen()
                }
            } else {
                OnboardingScreen()
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            tabState.lastSelectedTab = TabState.Tab.first
        }).tabItem {
            Label("Головна", image: "home-selected")
        }.tag(TabState.Tab.first)
    
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: AccountScreen(), isActive: $tabState.showTabRoots[1]) {
                Text("Hello World!")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
                     tabState.lastSelectedTab = TabState.Tab.second
                 }).tabItem {
                     Label("Профайл", image: "account-selected")
                 }.tag(TabState.Tab.second)
    }
    .onReceive(tabState.$selectedTab) { selection in
               if selection == tabState.lastSelectedTab {
                   tabState.showTabRoots[selection.rawValue] = false
               }
           }
    }
}
```

TabState:

```
class TabState: ObservableObject {
enum Tab: Int, CaseIterable {
    case first = 0
    case second = 1
    case third = 2
    case fourth = 3
}
    
@Published var selectedTab: Tab = .first
@Published var lastSelectedTab: Tab = .first

@Published var showTabRoots = Tab.allCases.map { _ in
    false
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to remember the full navigation stack you need to keep it in your model with one toggle for each subview . So the state of view hierarchy is saved in a tab.